# How to run AQL from Foxx

Tags: arangodb

I need to run some queries that the Foxx Repository object doesn't seem capable of handling (Maybe I'm just missing something). I'd like to use AQL, but I don't know how to call it from Foxx.

Example:

**timestamps** Collection:

```
{ user_id, time_stamp }
```

SQL Query (What I'd like to emulate):

```
SELECT * FROM timestamps WHERE user_id = 1024 AND time_stamp < 123456789
```

I can do:

```
timestamps.byExample( {user_id:1024} )
```

But this doesn't let me do a range as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In principle you can use the normal queries in a controller method. This will circumvent the Foxx repository methods, but should work. Example:

```
  controller.around("/hallo", function (req, res, options, next) {
    var count = true;
    var data = db._query("FOR u IN _users FILTER u.user == @name RETURN u",
                         { name: "root" }).toArray();

    res.json({ result: data });
  });
```

That is OK, if you want to use non-Foxx collections. If you need a Foxx collection the name depends on the mount point, in this case you need to use collectionName. Say, your collection is called "texts", then use

```
  controller.around("/hallo", function (req, res, options, next) {
    var count = true;
    var data = db._query("FOR u IN @@texts RETURN u",
                         { '@texts': applicationContext.collectionName("texts") }).toArray();

    res.json({ result: data });
  });
```